# I need a proof explanation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

Solve the equation $y^3 = x^3 + 8x^2 - 6x + 8$ for positive integers $x$ and $y$.

The given solution is:

[image: given_solution]

In the answer, how do we realise that we need to first subtract both sides by $(x+1)^3$ to get the inequality $x+1<y$ and then subtract the entire equation from $(x+3)^3$ to find the second inequality $x+3>y$.

i.e. Why $(x+1)^3$ and $(x+3)^3$ are involved and not $(x\pm n)^3$ where $n$ can be any natural number? How do we arrive at $n = 1$ and $3$ exactly?

Comment: I think because not for all $n$ we can have discriminant to be negative and thus the expression to be always positive.

Comment: Can you explain elaborately?

Comment: Yeah why not. I posted it as an answer and hope this solves your problem.

Comment: The key thing is to visually observe  that $ (x+1)^3 < x^3 + 8x^2 - 6x + 8 < (x+3)^3 $ and because we are dealing with integers, $x^3 + 8x^2 - 6x + 8$ must be equal to $ (x+2)^3$